# Segmenting video and encoding segments individually

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to build something like server farm for video encoding (encoding for http live streaming (segmented MPEG-TS)). So I need to split large video at master node, transfer each segment to nodes and encode them individually.

The first thing I must to do is segmenting this large video, so I need to find keyframes closest to each 10 seconds. I tried `ffprobe`, but it's really slow.

```
ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v input.mp4
```

Then I tried `ffmpeg`, and native segmenter, but I'm not sure if my command line is fine:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -segment_format mp4 -segment_list /dev/null -flags +global_header -map 0 -segment_time 10 -y stream%3d.mp4
```

And

```
ffmpeg -i stream000.mp4 -r 24 -vcodec libx264 -an -s 480x270 -b:v 400k 00.ts
```

on each node. It encoded fine (no error), but playback isn't smooth when it plays from previous to next chunk.

Maybe someone know how to do it right?